# RecyclerView limit items selected

Tags: android

For context this recyclerView is for a multiple choice question, and the recyclerView displays the options that the user can select to answer the question, these multiple choice question can have a different number of required options.

This is the adapter right now

```
public class CheckboxAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CheckboxAdapter.CheckboxViewHolder> {

    private static List<SurveyQuestionOptions> mOptions;
    private static List<SurveyQuestions> mQuestions;

    private static SparseBooleanArray itemsState = new SparseBooleanArray();

    public static class CheckboxViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        CheckBox checkBox;

        public CheckboxViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        }

        void bind(int position) {
            if (!itemsState.get(position, false)) {
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
            }
            checkBox.setText(mOptions.get(position).getOption());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();

            SurveyQuestionOptions currentOptions = mOptions.get(position);
            Optional<SurveyQuestions> currentQuestion = mQuestions.stream()
                    .filter(c -> c.getId().equals(currentOptions.getSurveyQuestionId())).findFirst();

            //none of this system prints appear in the console logcat

            if (itemsState.size() <= currentQuestion.get().getNum()) {
                System.out.println("first if");
                if (!itemsState.get(position, false)) {
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    itemsState.put(position, true);
                    System.out.println("checked");
                } else {
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                    itemsState.put(position, false);
                    System.out.println("unchecked");
                }
            }

        }

    }

    public CheckboxAdapter(List<SurveyQuestionOptions> optionsList, List<SurveyQuestions> questionsList) {
        mOptions = optionsList;
        mQuestions = questionsList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CheckboxViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_survey_question_multichoice_checkboxes, parent, false);
        return new CheckboxViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CheckboxViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(position);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mOptions == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return mOptions.size();
        }

    }
}
```

How can I fix that onClick so that when the number of required options is met the rest of the checkboxes become disabled?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add to `SurveyQuestionOptions` a property `enabled`
2. in `onClick` check the count of selected items
3. if `count == max` => set unselected `SurveyQuestionOptions` to `enabled` = false
4. in `bind(int position)` check if `SurveyQuestionOptions.enabled` = true

Comment: add the property `enabled` to the model or where?